# Scala inheritance: why do I have to define my classes to be abstract?

Tags: scala, class, inheritance

```
class inheritance
{ 
  def a()
  println("Version 1")
}

class inheritance1 
{
  def b()
  println("version 2")
}

class inheritance2 extends inheritance 
{
  def c()
  println("version 3")
}

class inheritance3 extends inheritance2 
{
  def d()
  println("version 4")
}

object inherited 
{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    var obj = new inheritance3
    obj.d
    obj.c 
  }
}
```

It throws a few errors:

```
class inheritance needs to be abstract since method a is not defined 

class inheritance1 needs to be abstract since method b is not defined 

class inheritance2 needs to be abstract since it has two unimplemented members 

class inheritance3 needs to be abstract since it has two unimplemented members
```

Comment: define the methods?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but please be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
def a()
println("foo")
```

Declares an undefined method `a` that takes no parameters and returns `Nothing` and then prints out a string.

```
def a() = println("foo")
```

or

```
def a() {
  println("foo")
}
```

or

```
def a() = 
  println("foo")
```

Define a method `a`, that prints out a string and returns a `Unit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dima for your reply but it is  still the same error

Comment: @ShellyVerma No, it isn't.  `class inheritance { def a() = println("Version 1") }` Does not give any errors.

Comment: I am sorry Dima to trouble you but it now throws no error as I  re-wrote the code. Thanks again :))))

Comment: could you please explain me how does it make difference when methods are defined or undefined. I mean the logic behind